# Sending special characters with Socket.io from a NodeJS server

Tags: javascript, node.js, utf-8, socket.io, special-characters

I have an app built on NodeJS which broadcasts strings to the client using Socket.io, and then the client updates the DOM with the new data recieved.

I have a problem with special characters. After console logging the outgoing data on the server, and the incoming data on the client, the strings are different.

So for example, the Node server logs *'音響式信号 福岡県八女市本村 清水町交差点（県道4号線方向）'*, but the incoming message on the client side logs *'é³é¿å¼ä¿¡å· ç¦å²¡çå«å¥³å¸æ¬æ æ¸æ°´çºäº¤å·®ç¹ï¼çé4å·ç·æ¹åï¼'*

I haven't done anything in with the data — just logging it as it comes.

Server:

```
var data = videos[cursor];
io.sockets.emit('send-now-next', data);
console.log(data.title) //logs the correct string in the Node Terminal
```

Client:

```
function onSendNowNext(data){
        console.log(data.title); //any special characters in the string will display incorrectly
    }

socket.on('send-now-next', onSendNowNext);
```

Comment: Please show us your code so we can see how you are sending and receiving the data.  Are you sending strings?  Buffers?  May want to read this: http://socket.io/blog/introducing-socket-io-1-0/#binary and this: https://github.com/automattic/engine.io-client#sending-and-receiving-binary

Comment: Have added code above. Thanks for the links, I'll wrap my head around them.